# I want Get Is Equal operator in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, logical-operators

I want Get  Is Equal operator in VB.net like in Java (A==B),
I tried this, but the results are not true,
What is the reason for that?

```
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine((100 <> 100) And False)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. `100 <> 100` is False, and `False and False` is False. For more information, see [And Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator). This means that the code you've posted is producing the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want an equality comparison.

On VB.net the equality operator is just `=`

Therefore `False = False` returns `True`

Based on your example `Console.WriteLine((100 <> 100) = False)` should result in `True`

For reference: [Comparison operators on VB.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators)